# Set Time.zone only for one command in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to parse a string to a Time object in Rails. This string is in another timezone than the default app timezone. So now, when I parse the string I first have to store the current/default time zone, change the time zone, parse the string and change the time zone back to default. That's 4 lines of code to to one thing:

```
current_timezone = Time.zone
Time.zone = "Target time zone"
Time.zone.parse("Tue Nov 23 23:29:57 2010") 
Time.zone = current_timezone
```

Is there a way to tell Rails inside the `parse` command which time zone to use?

Comment: You can do this `"Tue Nov 23 23:29:57 2010".to_datetime.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Time.in_zone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-use_zone) allows you to do this a little more idiomatically.

```
# Acting with the rails default timezone
Time.use_zone("America/New_York") do
  # Acting with the target timezone
  Time.zone.parse("Tue Nov 23 23:29:57 2010") #=> Tue, 23 Nov 2010 23:29:57 EST -05:00
end
# Acting with the rails default timezone
```

Comment: Thanks, I find this a lot cleaner.